# Python problem with opening password protected Excel file

Tags: python, excel

I would like to open my Excel file which is password protected. I've used some of the ways but without any success so far.

My recent approach is based on the Pandas library, which cannot read the password-protected Excel file.

The code looks like this:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import os, sys
 import win32com.client

 def unprotect_xlsx(filename):
   xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
   pw_str = 'Protektor'
   wb = xcl.workbooks.open(filename)
   wb.Unprotect(pw_str)
   wb.UnprotectSharing(pw_str)
   xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
   wb.Save()
   xsc.Quit

  if __name__ == '__main__':
   filename = 'C:\my\Cost.xlsx'
   unprotect_xslx(filename)

   df = pd.read_excel('C:\my\Cost.xlsx')

   print (df)
```

I am getting an error:

```
   NameError: name 'unprotect_xslx' is not defined
```

Which means, that the implementation of above doesn't work.

Is there any solution of how could I open the password-protected file?

Comment: Is the indentation in the code you posted exactly the same as in the code you're trying to run? Your `if __name__ == '__main__':` line is indented with two spaces when it shouldn't be at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just made a mistake spelling the function!

When you defined the function, you called it: `unprotect_xlsx()`
But when calling it, you called it: `unprotect_xslx()`

Note the difference in spelling `xlsx` and `xslx`! Change it and it should work just fine! :)